# Mysql Inner join... Erro Column 'Id_ocorrencia' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

Eu quero acessar dados de duas tabelas diferentes: `ocorrencia` e `fotos`.

- Na tabela `fotos` tenho um campo que é a `id_ocorrencia` *(que cria a relação - chave estrangeira)*.
- Na tabela `ocorrencia` não tem chave estrangeira da tabela `fotos`.

Quando executo essa consulta:

```
select 
  nome_foto 
from 
  ocorrencia 
inner join fotos 
  on fotos.id_ocorrencia=ocorrencia.id_ocorrencia
```

dá certo, mas quando executo este:

```
select 
  Id_ocorrencia, nome_foto 
from
  ocorrencia 
inner join fotos 
  on fotos.id_ocorrencia=ocorrencia.id_ocorrencia
```

dá errado

Answer (score 2):

Como a mensagem de erro já diz a coluna `id_ocorrencia` está definida de modo ambíguo, ou seja, ela existe em mais de uma tabela e você não está definindo de qual tabela o banco de dados deve obter a informação. Basta adicionar alias as tabelas para que o banco de dados entenda a sua instrução:

```
SELECT f.Id_ocorrencia,
       f.nome_foto
  FROM ocorrencia o
 INNER JOIN fotos f ON f.id_ocorrencia = o.id_ocorrencia
```

Answer (score 2):

A coluna existe nas **duas as tabelas**, o banco de dados não sabe de qual delas mostrar, ocorrendo a ambiguidade.

Adicione o `alias` da tabela que você deseja apresentar o dado:

```
select ocorrencia.id_ocorrencia, nome_foto from ocorrencia inner join fotos on fotos.id_ocorrencia=ocorrencia.id_ocorrencia
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ocorrencia.Id_ocorrencia, nome_foto from ocorrencia inner join fotos on fotos.id_ocorrencia=ocorrencia.id_ocorrencia
```

Faltou o alias antes da seleção do campo ID_OCORRENCIA>

Comment: como ficaria Andrey?